# Linq group data by week data or dates and sum

Tags: asp.net, linq, datatable, group-by, sum

I have a datatable with 2 weeks of data. I want to group and sum the records. For ex:

EDIT :The datatypes of the columns are int,datetime,double respectively.

> UserID    WorkDay        HrsWorked
>
> 1                 2/7/2010 
>        2(8-10am)
>
> 1         2/7/2010       
>   6(12-6pm)

```
   2  2/7/2010 1(9-10am)
```

> 2          2/7/2010
>       7(12-7pm)

...

So I have data like this from 2/7 to 2/20. I want to get the hours the user worked by weekly i.e (2/7/2010-2/13/2010) and (2/14/2010-2/20/2010). Right now my linq query on the datatable just gives me the sum of hours for 2 weeks. So I ended with data like this

userID HRSWorked

> 1         74.67
>
> 2          82.33

I want to get like this

> userID    HRSworked       WeekWorked
>
> 1        
>   40                
>   2/7/2010-2/13/2010
>
> 1       34.67
>            2/14/2010-2/20/2010

same for userId 2

```
Dim groupedData = From row In mydataTable _
                  Group row By UserID = row.Field(Of Int32)("UserID") Into UserIDGroup = Group _
                  Select New With { _
                     Key UserID, _
                        .HrsWorked = UserIDGroup.Sum(Function(r) r.Field(Of Double("HrsWorked")) _
                  }
```

If you need more info, please ask. Thanks

Comment: Well you've managed the grouping... but we don't know the type of the data for the dates (nor even the field names) so it's hard to say how you can group by that...

Comment: @JonSkeet. My bad. The columns are UserID,WorkDay(I wrote it as Date here) and HrsWorked. DataTypes are int,datetime,double respectively. Will that help?Again if you need info,please ask.

Comment: I suggest you edit this into the question... then think carefully about what you want to group by. (Hint: it's not just a single column.)